# Binding Kendo UI spreadshhet to an empty datasource

Tags: kendo-ui

I am wanting to initially bind a Kendo UI spreadsheet to an empty datasource so the user is presented with an empty sheet. However I am running into this issue:

> The data of the DataSource to which the Spreadsheet will be bound has to contain data items. Binding the widget to a DataSource with empty data leads to undesired side effects.

Is there any known workaround to this issue?

Comment: Show the code you are using to declare the spreadsheet, or create an example in dojo (https://dojo.telerik.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Why bind to an empty data source ?  You could initialize an empty spreadsheet and use the `sheets` the initializer creates for it.  A spreadsheet always has at least one sheet.

```
<div id="spreadsheet" style="width: 100%;"></div>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#spreadsheet").kendoSpreadsheet({
    });
});
</script>
```